# Push data from SQL Server on Prem into SQL Azure for PowerBI purposes

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, etl

I am new to PowerBI and have uploaded PIBX files for use by PowerBI, however, I have a scenario where I have some data in a local SQL Server but I want to get it into SQL Azure (preferably an automated push twice per day) so that I can create some PowerBI Embedded reports.

I am not sure what the best approach is, if I should be pushing it somehow or pulling it, or what tools to use to do this?

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many approaches you can use, to push data from Onpremises to Azure..

**1.SSIS**

You can write an SSIS data flow task

**2.Replication**

You can replicate your Onpremises database to azure starting from SQLAzure v12

**3.write a console application and schedule it through SQLAgent**

I would go with Replication,since it reduces the effort of knowing what to sync and what not to

refer below link for more details on how to do this
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transactional-replication-to-azure-sql-db/